# ISAPIREWRITE - Access to an external site without changing the url of my domain

Tags: isapi-rewrite

How to make a redirect from my website to an external website without losing my domain url using isapirewrite. For example my site has access to mydomain.com/IT esternaldomain.com, which upon entering the url link that should be mydomain.com/IT/Details

Answer (score 0):

Actually the syntax may vary from the version (2 vs 3). Here's a generic example of a PROXY rule for ISAPI_Rewrite3:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^IT$ http://esternaldomain.com [NC,P,L]
```